# My uploader doesnt seem to work (CodeIgniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I was trying to use a uploader called MAX file upload. A controller calls a view called upload_view.php. Here are the codes for it: 
 [Both these codes are placed in the application/views folder]

upload_view.php

```
<?php require_once("maxUpload.class.php"); ?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
   <title>Max's File Uploader</title>
   <link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<?php
    $myUpload = new maxUpload(); 
    //$myUpload->setUploadLocation(getcwd().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
    $myUpload->uploadFile();
?>
</body>
```

and here is the maxUpload.class.php

```
<?php
/*************************************************
 * Max's File Uploader
 *
 * Version: 1.0
 * Date: 2007-11-26
 *
 ****************************************************/
class maxUpload{
    var $uploadLocation;

    /**
     * Constructor to initialize class varaibles
     * The uploadLocation will be set to the actual 
     * working directory
     *
     * @return maxUpload
     */
    function maxUpload(){
        $this->uploadLocation = getcwd().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    }

    /**
     * This function sets the directory where to upload the file
     * In case of Windows server use the form: c:\\temp\\
     * In case of Unix server use the form: /tmp/
     *
     * @param String Directory where to store the files
     */
    function setUploadLocation($dir){
        $this->uploadLocation = $dir;
    }

    function showUploadForm($msg='',$error=''){
?>
       <div id="container">
            <div id="header"><div id="header_left"></div>
            <div id="header_main">Max's File Uploader</div><div id="header_right"></div></div>
            <div id="content">
<?php
if ($msg != ''){
    echo '<p class="msg">'.$msg.'</p>';
} else if ($error != ''){
    echo '<p class="emsg">'.$error.'</p>';

}
?>
                <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
                     <center>
                         <label>File:
                             <input name="myfile" type="file" size="30" />
                         </label>
                         <label>
                             <input type="submit" name="submitBtn" class="sbtn" value="Upload" />
                         </label>
                     </center>
                 </form>
             </div>
             <div id="footer"><a href="http://www.phpf1.com" target="_blank">Powered by PHP F1</a></div>
         </div>
<?php
    }

    function uploadFile(){
        if (!isset($_POST['submitBtn'])){
            $this->showUploadForm();
        } else {
            $msg = '';
            $error = '';

            //Check destination directory
            if (!file_exists($this->uploadLocation)){
                $error = "The target directory doesn't exists!";
            } else if (!is_writeable($this->uploadLocation)) {
                $error = "The target directory is not writeable!";
            } else {
                $target_path = $this->uploadLocation . basename( $_FILES['myfile']['name']);

                if(@move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
                    $msg = basename( $_FILES['myfile']['name']).
                    " was uploaded successfully!";
                } else{
                    $error = "The upload process failed!";
                }
            }

            $this->showUploadForm($msg,$error);
        }

    }

}
?>
```

Whenever i add something like

```
$query = $this->db->get('filename');
                $folder_name = underscore($query->row()->file_name);
```

inside the function maxuplod() in the maxUpload.class.php file, the upload page doesnt show up. I use this $folder_name later to add it to the download dir, so that custom folders can be created.

When this code is placed within maxUpload.class.php, it doesnt  load anything. Error log shows an error at the same line the db is accessed. Without it the files can be uploaded to a static upload folder.

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: is there any reason for using `MAX file upload` instead of codeigniters file upload class ??

Comment: Im trying to upload multiple files, which when uploaded will be saved in the folder name obtained from the DB. I've tried uploadify, uploadifive etc. but wasnt able to save them in dynamic folders. Any suggestions?

Comment: have a looke to plupload .. jquery based file upload plugins.. super easy to use and nice desgin.. flexible